# Is there any way I can create a .sqlite file using local R dataframe?

Tags: r, sqlite

Is there any way I can create a .sqlite file using a local R data frame?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Just use your favorite internet search engine and serach for R sqlite. Then you will find: rsqlite.r-dbi.org that shows you an example. 
More examples ca be found in StackOverflow, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332976/how-to-import-csv-into-sqlite-using-rsqlite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
library(DBI)

con = dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(),dbname = 'test.db')
dbWriteTable(conn = con, name = "Tbl_test", value = mtcars)
dbListTables(conn = con)
#> [1] "Tbl_test"
dbDisconnect(con)

dir(".")
#>[1] "test.db"
```

Comment: Hi @Waldi: a question to the experienced SO user: what is the recommended way to answer such basic questions: with a code example or just by links to available resources?

Comment: @tpezoldt, difficult to tell, however link to available ressources should stay in comments, and code example is an answer.